# How to make partition on additional drive having already Windows and Ubuntu installed on C drive (dual boot)?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have made a partition on C drive and now have both Windows and Linux installed on this drive (dual boot). Now I would like to create a partition on additional D drive which is now dedicated only to Windows and add some of created disk space to Ubuntu. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to elaborate on your question. When you refer to drive C and D, are those separate physical disks in your computer? If so, how much space do you have on those disks?

If you could paste the output / screenshot of Gparted / Disks, that would help us to guide you.

Comment: In Windows the term D drive can mean a partition in the same physical SSD/HDD or a different physical SSD/HDD. It is not clear from the question if you have 2 separate physical drives or 2 partitions C and D.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend making a backup (I personally prefer a drive clone) before attempting any repartitioning. After doing that I believe you can do what you seek through the LiveCD containing your present version of Linux, boot with that and use Gparted.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to allocate more space to Ubuntu. One great way to do that is to shrink the D drive on your Windows and add the space to Ubuntu. You can do that as follows :
1. Create a bootable USB stick containing GParted, a partitioning utility.
2. Shrink the Windows partition.
3. Expand the Ubuntu partition using GParted.

Detailed explanation is given here : http://joejanuszk.com/blog/increasing-ubuntu-partition-size-dual-boot-windows/

Be careful to take a backup of your important files though!